# Quickbooks PHP integration tax error

Tags: php, quickbooks

I'm trying to integrate Quickbooks using PHP using the sample code provided. This is for India with revised tax system. For the add invoice code, I'm getting this error:

> error 6000:A business validation error has occurred while processing
>   your request, Business Validation Error:
>
> Make sure all your transactions have a sales tax rate before you save.

My code:

```
$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();


$Invoice = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();

$Invoice->setDocNumber('WEB' . mt_rand(0, 10000));
$Invoice->setTxnDate('2013-10-11');

$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$Line->setAmount(20.0000 * 1.0000 * 0.516129);
$Line->setDescription('Test description goes here.');

$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef('8');
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(20 * 0.516129);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(1.00000);
$SalesItemLineDetail->settax(10.00000);


$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);

$Invoice->addLine($Line);


$Invoice->setCustomerRef('67');


//if ($resp = $InvoiceService->add($Context, $realm, $Invoice)){
if ($resp = $InvoiceService->add($Context , $realm, $Invoice)){

    print('Our new Invoice ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
}else{

    print($InvoiceService->lastError());
}
```

There is no parameter for tax specified in the documentation, nor the parameters in invoice response is fixing this. Can anyone share the exact parameters to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code and parameter for tax specified in the documentation,the parameters in invoice response is fixied

```
$Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
$Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
$Line->setAmount(20.0000 * 1.0000 * 0.516129);
$Line->setDescription('test');
$SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
$SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef('1');
$SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(20 * 0.516129);
$SalesItemLineDetail->setQty(1.00000);
/*Tax Calculation*/
$SalesItemLineDetail->setTaxCodeRef("2");
$SalesItemLineDetail->set("DetailType","Sale Tax");
$SalesItemLineDetail->set("TaxPercent","8.25");
$SalesItemLineDetail->set("PercentBased","true");
$SalesItemLineDetail->set("IsTaxable", "true");
$SalesItemLineDetail->settax(10.00000);
$Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);
$Invoice->addLine($Line);
$Invoice->setCustomerRef('90');
```